# How to add Super Password to CakePHP 2.0 Authentication

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, passwords

There is specific request from my client to add possibility of "Super Login" to application, which will enable him to log in as any user thanks to Super Password. I am thinking in this way: Somewhere in CakePHP Auth process adding a condition which will enable using special string as password, so with this string user will we authenticated through $this->Auth->login() method he is logged in by normal way using users password.
Has anyone did this before? Is there any way how to obtain this goal?

here are my lines of code in UserController, which does the authentication for user:

```
    public function admin_login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully Logged In'),'flash_custom_success');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'),'flash_custom_error');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there no way to convince your client that this is über-insecure? Anyone with the SuperPassword (soundtrack needed) will wreak havoc... Specially if he wants and "easy" password to remember and ends up with "superPassword123"

Comment: I agree, probably better way, would be to add possibility for admin to switch to another user. Background logic would just rewrite $user array in Session, that should do the wanted effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking (and not liking the "Super Password" idea) i decided to create user switch functionality for administrators. This solution was accepted by client.